# Promise in promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, es6-promise

How to handle next promise problem situation: I need to resolve pets for each person, fire event after pets is resolved and fire last event when all persons are resolved:

```
(async() => {
    const personsArr = await Promise.all(persons.map(async (person) => {
        await someSyncFunc();
        const petsArr = await Promise.all(pets.map(async (pet) => {
          await asyncSetPetName(pet, person);
        }));
        Promise.resolve(petsArr)
            .then(async () => someSyncFunc());
            .then(() => console.log('pets resolved'));
    }));
    Promise.resolve(personsArr)
        .then(async  () => someSyncFunc());
        .then(() => console.log('persons resolved'));
})();
```

Problem is first `Promise.resolve` is count for personsArr.

Comment: You missed `await` before first `Promise.all`

Comment: My target is to fire console.log('persons resolved') after update all persons: for each person > update his pet, update person himself, fire event at the end

Comment: probably not the issue, but you're missing a `return` on that final `Promise.resolve()` call.

Comment: Do you really want to call `asyncSetPetName` with *every* combination of pet and person?

Comment: @TeodorKolev TBH, it's not entirely clear what your problem is, because you haven't said what your expected output is.   As @Bergi said, you don't need all those extra `Promise.resolve().then()` chains, and it does seem a little odd that you apparently call `asyncSetPetName` for every possible combination of `pet` and `person`.

Comment: @Alnitak does it make more sense now?

Comment: @TeodorKolev no, not really, and the fact you've changed the code invalidates answers already supplied.   Your code will log "pets resolved" once for every person, and it's unclear it that's intended.   Your last line is completely unclear (I can't parse what you think the problem actually is).

Comment: My target is to log 'person resolved' after all persons are resolved. In practice it is fired before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `Promise.resolve(arr).then(…)` doesn't make any sense. Not only is `arr` already an array (nothing that needs to be resolved), but also you shouldn't use `then` when working with `async`/`await`:

```
(async() => {
    const personsArr = await Promise.all(persons.map(async (person) => {
        const petsArr = await Promise.all(pets.map(async (pet) => {
            return asyncSetPetName(pet, person);
        }));
        console.log('pets resolved');
    }));
    console.log('persons resolved');
})();
```

Comment: the arrow function in the outer `persons.map()` call isn't returning a value, so `personsArr` will be full of `undefined` values.

Comment: @Alnitak True. Maybe I should have removed the variable declarations entirely, as they are not used at all.